# How to return and notify data from async web service

Tags: android, web-services, asynchronous

I'm developing an application for Android API8.
This application is essentially 4 'pages' of choices (simply a ListView) and a final page with a web page that depends on the previous choices: every page is a list of items returned by a webservice request, queried by a specific query formed by an URL+parameters (REST POST).
My initial idea is to have some activities that access to a common Protocol class: this class has some public members (GetPage1Items(), GetPage2Items(), ..) each of them creates an appropriate URL and runs a common SendRequest() function that sends and receives the HTTP data. This function could be based on a AsyncTask implementation.
Main activity should call one of the public Protocol function and wait for a reply with a ProgressDialog.

My problems are:

```
 - how to notify to the activity that the data is ready in the Protocol class?  
 - how to have a common Protocol class for all the activities? (I should pass the class to every activity..)
```

Or better to have a ProtocolBase abstract class with the common HTTP protocol routines and a set of overridable functions to implement each different request (for Page1, Page2, ...). Each activity should implement a specialized ProtocolBase class. BTW I should keep an initial token  that I need to include in every request: how can i handle it (static)? and, again, how to notify the data ready?
Maybe inside the onPostExecute() I should access to the ListView passing data to its Adapter?

Thanks

Comment: how abt postexecute in asyntask?

Comment: `Maybe inside the onPostExecute() I should access to the ListView passing data to its Adapter?`Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common AsyncTask class and define a Interface and let your activities implement that interfaces, and in onpostexecute of asynctask we will do a call back to the interface method, for reference [Check this link](http://cyriltata.blogspot.in/2013/10/android-re-using-asynctask-class-across.html)

Hope it helps!!!